# Count iteration of random entries

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

On my spreadsheet I have a list of 20 items. Each item is assigned a number, and I use a random number generator to randomly select one item from the list of 20 and display it in an adjacent cell.

I would like to have an additional number next to each item on the list which increases by 1 every time that item is selected. How can I use formulas to count the iterations of each item on the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "a random number generator"? Are you using a built-in function, an addon or a script? Did you already search for a similar question on this site? Reference [ask].

Comment: I did look on the site for similar questions but didn't find anything that quite fit.I use the function RANDBETWEEN  to generate the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Possible but in general inadvisable to do so with formulae only. Say your list is in A1 to A20 and the selection is made in C1.

In File > Spreadsheet settings... > Calculation set Recalculation to On change and turn On iterative calculation with Max. number of iterations set to `1`.

Temporarily disable the formula in C1 and in B1 enter:

```
=B1+(C$1=A1)
```

and extend the series down to suit, then re-enable the formula in C1.